# For repeating html , good to go with template or directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Implementing below feature, when user clicks on Add button , new conext is getting added.

I created that context as directive, Am not sure whether i should create this just as template and repeat using ng-repeat or using directive is better.

[image: directive or template]

Comment: Unless you're going to be using the same markup else where, I would go with a straight ng-repeat.

Comment: @Gavin apart form reuseability is there any other benefit like, performance improvement for not using directive, just curious to know

Comment: i will create a directive who display the context/note/delete button and use it in a ng-repeat. you cannot just create a template without directive because of the ng-model binding in input and the button should a function with a specifique id too

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a directive. I personally find its a good way to encapsulate code. It makes it re-usable, and there is absolutely no performance issues doing so. AngularJS will run smoothly to about 2000 directives within the same page.

Doing it in a directive will also allow you to use functionalities later on you might not have predicted to use.